# Kubernetes ingress rules: How to use wildcard and specific subdomain together

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

I want Ingress to redirect a specific subdomain to one backend and all others to other backend. Basically, I want to define a rule something like the following:

> If subdomain is `foo.bar.com` then go to `s1`, for all other subdomains go to `s2`

When I define the rules as shown below in the Ingress spec, I get this exception at deployment:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: cannot re-use a name that is still in use
```

When I change `*.bar.com` to `demo.bar.com` it works, however.

Here's my Ingress resource spec:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: s1
          servicePort: 80
  - host: *.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: s2
          servicePort: 80
```

Anyone has an idea if it is possible or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now possible in [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#hostname-wildcards) with nginx:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: web-static-ip
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-alias: www.foo.bar
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
  name: foo-bar-ingress
  namespace: test
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 'foo.bar.com'
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: specific-service
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  - host: '*.bar.com'
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: general-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is currently not possible when looking at Issue [41881](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/41881), but I could be missing something in the most recent version of Kubernetes—we're about to [release 1.12](https://github.com/kubernetes/sig-release/tree/master/releases/release-1.12) as we speak.

Comment: Well, I hope one of the GKE folks here chimes in and proofs me wrong ;)

Answer (score 1):

THere is already a PR raised for supporting the wild card domains in ingress rules.
refer the below link

https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3884

Can you try Traefik v1.7 and see if the wild card support is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a default backend -

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  - backend:
      serviceName: s2
      servicePort: 80
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: s1
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: I think this is `defaultBackend` now.